# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: android, facebook

I want to excess the user's photos and albums and

My code is:

```
Session session;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
    statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()){
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"))
        .setCallback(statusCallback));
    }else{
        Session.openActiveSession(FbGallery.this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened() && session!=null) 
        {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                {
                    //  callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                 if (user != null) {
                            gallery(session);
                 }
                    }
                    });
                }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I guess everything is fine in the code but why is this error showing::

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1/jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1.FbGallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Stack Trace

```
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1/jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1.FbGallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1.FbGallery.onActivityResult(FbGallery.java:154)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
05-01 12:34:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(19178):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post a full stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @Karakuri: I have added my stack trace please review it...:)

Comment: Session.getActiveSession() is probably returning `null`.

Comment: @Karakuri: Ya it is returning `null` but why?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what `Session` is (because I do not see the import statement) and also have no idea what this code is supposed to do, so I can't tell you. All I can tell you is that method is returning `null`, and trying to dereference a null pointer (using the `.` operator) causes a NullPointerException.